# Compiling Boost on Cygwin, headers disagree on 32/64 bit

Tags: c++, boost, cygwin, compiler-warnings

I'm trying to compile the latest boost on Cygwin and I'm getting tons of warnings like these:

```
...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-4.9.2/release/link-static/threading-multi/object_protocol.o...
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-4.9.2/release/link-static/threading-multi/object_operators.o
In file included from ./boost/python/detail/prefix.hpp:13:0,
                 from ./boost/python/object_operators.hpp:8,
                 from libs\python\src\object_operators.cpp:6:
./boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:88:0: warning: "SIZEOF_LONG" redefined
 #  define SIZEOF_LONG 4
 ^
In file included from ./boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:50:0,
                 from ./boost/python/detail/prefix.hpp:13,
                 from ./boost/python/object_operators.hpp:8,
                 from libs\python\src\object_operators.cpp:6:
/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:1013:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define SIZEOF_LONG 8
```

I am on a 64 bit system. pyconfig.h gets it right, the size of a long should be 8. wrap_python.hpp in boost has it wrong.

I looked at wrap_python.hpp and found this:

```
//
// Some things we need in order to get Python.h to work with compilers other
// than MSVC on Win32
//
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(__CYGWIN__)
# if defined(__GNUC__) && defined(__CYGWIN__)

#  define SIZEOF_LONG 4
```

...which then causes this error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:58:0,
                 from ./boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:142,
                 from ./boost/python/detail/prefix.hpp:13,
                 from ./boost/python/converter/registrations.hpp:8,
                 from libs\python\src\object\function_doc_signature.cpp:9:
/usr/include/python2.7/pyport.h:886:2: error: #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
 #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
  ^
```

How do I make everything 64-bit?

Comment: I guess you installed 64-bits Cygwin. You probably need to compile with -m64 option to select a 64bit build (couldn't try it: my Cygwin is 32 bits and says "sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in")

Comment: This seems like a bug in Boost, that wrap_python.hpp just forces Cygwin to be 32-bits all the time. Or maybe there's some configure option I missed.

Comment: By Win32 convention, `long` should always be 32-bits regardless of whether you are compiling a 32-bit or 64-bit app.  You need `long long` if you want a 64-bit value.  If your compiler is doing something other than this, then it does not support Win32.  (Well, technically the type that must always be 32-bit is `LONG` -- it's up to you to be careful not to mix them up if your compiler decides that `long` and `LONG` are different types.)

Comment: Cygwin doesn't obey the Win32 convention when it comes to 64 bit: https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/programming.html#gcc  . This makes stuff easier to port, like in my case :)

Answer (score 0):

To compile correctly, all you need to do is to change

```
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(__CYGWIN__)
# if defined(__GNUC__) && defined(__CYGWIN__)
#  define SIZEOF_LONG 4
```

to

```
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(__CYGWIN__)
# if defined(__GNUC__) && defined(__CYGWIN__)
#  define SIZEOF_LONG 8
```

in the */boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp* file.
Tested under Cygwin-64 with GCC-4.9.3.
See also [here](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/684).
Perhaps you have found your own solution, but I hope this answer could help others.